# Installation error : Unknown Failure on L build when running the application from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently developing an app and it works fine when I try to install it on a mobile running Kit Kat but when I try to run it on a device having L preview, the logcat displays an error stating  “Installation Error: Unknown Failure”.

I tried changing the target and  the target SDK version to L but no luck. I also downloaded the SDK platform for L  ( API 20, L preview).

Is there anything else I need to download ? Any inputs would be deeply appreciated.

My Logcat display the messages shown below :

```
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): linux_qmi_qmux_io.c: Unable to open port id /dev/mhi_pipe_14, error [2:No such file or directory]
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_open_connection: QMI_QMUX_IO_PLATFORM_OPEN_CONN failed -1 
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_tx_msg: failed to open inactive connd_id=57
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_open_connection: connection is disabled for conn_id=0
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_tx_msg: failed to open inactive connd_id=0
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux: TX failed, connection inactive or in reset, conn_id=0, status_flags=4
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_ctl_tx_msg: qmi_qmux_tx_msg failed
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_ctl_handle_request: qmi_ctl_tx_msg call failed
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_open_connection: connection is disabled for conn_id=0
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_tx_msg: failed to open inactive connd_id=0
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux: TX failed, connection inactive or in reset, conn_id=0, status_flags=4
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_ctl_tx_msg: qmi_qmux_tx_msg failed
01-01 17:56:34.102: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_ctl_handle_request: qmi_ctl_tx_msg call failed
01-01 17:56:34.103: E/QC-QMI(386): linux_qmi_qmux_io.c: Unable to open port id /dev/mhi_pipe_14, error [2:No such file or directory]
01-01 17:56:34.103: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_open_connection: QMI_QMUX_IO_PLATFORM_OPEN_CONN failed -1 
01-01 17:56:34.103: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_tx_msg: failed to open inactive connd_id=57
01-01 17:56:34.103: E/QC-QMI(335): qmi_client [335] 131: failed to locate client data
01-01 17:56:34.103: E/QC-QMI(386): qmuxd: RX on fd=18 returned error=0 errno[2:No such file or directory]
01-01 17:56:34.104: E/QC-QMI(386): qmi_qmux_tx_msg: failed to open inactive connd_id=57
```

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Check a little further in the LogCat. Usually for installation failures there's a reason logged somewhere nearby the actual error message.

Comment: Ihave edited my post...Could you let me know if there is anything I can do because I have no idea what those errors are?

Comment: Those seem unrelated. Clear your log, then attempt the install, and then capture the log after it fails.

Comment: These log messages are not related to your app, they are other error logs.